# Are there operations that can't be defined using a rule, and if they exist what is their significance?

Tags: terminology, education, philosophy, binary-operations

[Wikipedia:Operations(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics),)

> In mathematics, an operation is a function which takes zero or more input values (called operands) to a well-defined output value

What I took away from this fact was that operations are essentially just functions.

I know that a function could just be an *insignificant* set of ordered pairs, with no formula associated with it, for example, $$\{(red,255),(green,127),(blue,0)\}$$

Are there functions that can't be described by anything more complex than sets, and if they do exist how would we define or use them? Would these "operations" be considered functions, or would we still consider them to be operations?

Comment: You need to define what a "rule" is. Arguably, your set notation is a "rule."

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation

Comment: @AlekosRobotis I want to define a rule to be somewhat like a calculus/algebraic formula, but I also want it to mean anything more "less simple" than set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the vast, vast majority of functions on, say $\mathbb R$, have no “rule”.

This is not very surprising when you realize that there are at least as many functions as there are real numbers (because there are constant functions spitting out any real number) and the vast, vast majority of real numbers have no “rule”. So, any given human description can be encoded in the Unicode character set which maps it to a unique integer in $\mathbb N$. But, it is known that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is simply a larger infinity than $\mathbb N$ as the binary expansion of a number in $[0, 1)$ (except for some details about repeating 1s at the end of an expansion, which turn out to be immaterial) can be viewed as specifying a subset of $\mathbb N$ consisting of all indices which have a 1-bit there. The set of subsets of $S$ is always a larger cardinality than $S$, they cannot be put into one-to-one correspondence; and so too with $S = \mathbb N$.

But, this is also true also for functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb \{0, 1\}$ for example, and so the vast vast majority of functions from natural numbers to nontrivial sets are also indescribable in words or formulas.

Words and formulas can only exhaustively define all those functions from finite sets to sets which are either finite or countably infinite. Otherwise there are literally just not enough words to define some of the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the promp reply, could we consider these functions to be operations, and what use would they have as operations on say real numbers?

Comment: I mean you have to be careful with the word “operation” as it is close to the word “operator” which is different.

Comment: I guess to be an “operation” I would generally expect, say, continuity—and continuity *does* change this picture, there are $2^{\mathbb R}$ functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ but only $\mathbb R$ continuous functions (each continuous function is uniquely specified by its value on the rationals as a function $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$, using $\mathbb Q\sim\mathbb N^2\sim\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R~\sim~\mathbb N\to2$, we can see $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R~\sim~\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\to2$ which [curries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to $\mathbb N^2 \to2~\sim~\mathbb N\to2~\sim ~\mathbb R$.)

Comment: With that said it doesn't change the situation *enough*, you still have that the vast majority of continuous real functions are indescribable, with the obvious example that the constant functions are all continuous and they are indescribable because of how many reals there are. So yeah I anticipate that there are things you would regard as valid “operations” on the reals which cannot be put into words and thus will never be discovered.